# SQL - Дубликаты при использовании UPDATE и REPLACE(UUID())

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица, в которой необходимо создать UUID бинарного формата (binary(16)) для старых записей, которым он не задан. Выполняю запрос:

```
UPDATE `table` SET uuid=UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '')) WHERE uuid IS NULL;
```

И после обновления лишь одной записи получаю подобные ошибки:

> Дублирующаяся запись '\x8B';\xA6T\xAE\x11\xE7\x9B\x0F\xF0yYry\xD5' по
>   ключу 'uuid'

Подобное поведение наблюдается только при наличии REPLACE в запросе.
Товарищи специалисты, подскажите решение этой проблемы, пожалуйста.

Comment: А зачем там SELECT? да и со скобками беда... `UPDATE table SET uuid=UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '')) WHERE uuid IS NULL;`

Comment: Извиняюсь, намудрил со скобками при вставке запроса сюда.
SELECT появился в результате безуспешных попыток обойти эту странность с дублирующимся UUID(), без него в общем та же проблема.

Comment: Достаточно спрятать выражение вычисления `UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-', ''))` в функцию, которую объявить non-deterministic. Альтернативный вариант - использовать временную таблицу, в которой сгенерить заведомо достаточное количетсво UUID-ов, и обновлять из неё. PS. У меня на модели проблема не воспроизвелась, все записи получили уникальные значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что делаете вы:

1. Находите все записи без `uuid`
2. Генерируете один какой-то UUID
3. Каждую запись пытаетесь этим UUID обновить.

Если представить что ваш UUID, как среднее случайно число, равен четырём, то вы пытаетесь сделать примерно следующее:

```
UPDATE `table` SET uuid=4 WHERE uuid IS NULL;
```

Естественно возникает ошибка.

У этой проблемы есть правильные решения, и есть быстрые.

#### Быстрое решение

Если быстро, то можно выдумать свой собственный UUID, который вычисляется как функция от уникальной части строки в БД. Например, от её ID:

```
UPDATE `table` SET 
    `uuid` = UNHEX(MD5(CONCAT(UUID(), `id`))) 
    WHERE `uuid` IS NULL;
```

Так, каждая запись будет обновляться своим собственным, в какой-то мере случайным, UUID.

#### Правильное решение

Если нужно решить *правильно*, то, надеюсь, местные эксперты по хранимым процедурам наведут на правильное направление в другом ответе.